# asp.net send payments to paypal accounts

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal

I am developing an asp.net application where are 2 kinds of users: sellers and buyers. When a seller registers a new account, it is asked for the PayPal account.
The buyers have a shopping cart and the checkout is with PayPal. The money from checkout are going to different sellers PayPal accounts. The problem is I don't know how can I do this in an asp.net project. I saw lots of online tutorials, but all of them are using sandbox account for one user that receives payments.
Thanks!

Comment: Completely understand where his question is coming from. I am stuck on the same problem. The product that PayPal offers for this payment technique that Ebay uses (With sellers and customer PayPal integration) is `PayPal for Marketplaces` - more specifically, the `Connected Path`. The first step after registering with PayPal is the `Connected Onboarding` integration where sellers are made to register with PayPal.  If anyone knows of a tutorial for this, please leave it in the comments. The PayPal documentation is a bit too generic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot create dynamically Paypal accounts (for sellers) - and it looks like, this is what you want. All of the tutorials are for one user, that receives payment - because you are integrating paypal payments for one entity (user, company etc.) Probably there is api for transfering funds - so you can integrate your paypal account for buyers and after payment is done by them, you can transfer proper amount to seller account (the best would be to store their money on virtual system account and allow them to withdraw money from time to time)

Comment: For example websites like amazon, ebay and etsy are using this kind of payments. I use etsy as a seller and when a buyer submits an order using PayPal, the money are directly transferred to my seller PayPal account(When I created the etsy account, they asked me about PayPal account). This is the way I want to use PayPal on my website

Comment: Probably, what happens "behind the scenes" is, that buyer transfer money to Etsy, and Etsy is transfering money to you (instantly) Who is mentioned as transfer owner (Etsy or the buyer)?

Comment: The buyer appears appears with his name in my PayPal account